# Communicating with MiR200 Robot using REST API

Tags: python, json, robotics, rest

I have been trying to control the Mir 200 robot using REST API in python. I have programmed the mission in Mir to work only if the PLC register value changes, so I give the following request in python but I get a 405 error. Can anybody help me with the syntax? I try to change the PLC register 41 value to 5.

```py
register = {"value": 5}
PLCregister = requests.post(host + 'registers/41', json = register, headers = headers)
print(PLCregister)
```

Comment: Can you provide a source to the documentation on this robot?

Comment: `405` means not allowed, I'd take a look at the documentation for the MIR-200 (that's what anybody answering the question would have to do for you). You should update the question tags to make sure you get the right people viewing too.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with the MiR200 or any of their robots (they look cool and I'm a little jealous) but it looks like instead of a `POST` request, you can try a `PUT` request to modify the value. I'm going off this pdf: https://www.mobile-industrial-robots.com/media/2214/mir_robot_rest_api_200.pdf

The 405 error means the request method (`POST` in this case) is not allowed, maybe it has been deprecated.

You can try this:

```py
register = {'value': 5}
plc_register = requests.put(host + 'registers/41', json=register, headers=headers)
print(plc_register)
```

`POST` requests are generally used to tell the server to create data, not modify it. You can see they kinda mention this in the MiR 2.0.X documentation:

`POST /registers/{id}`

> Modify the value of the PLC register with the specified ID. Registers
> 1 to 100 are integers and registers 101-200 are float. `Even though this is not a standard use of the POST call it has been included for compatibility purposes`

So, maybe the `POST` method is not in your robot's software, just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I change the register value.

```
 requests.put(host + 'registers/11', '{"value":23}', headers = headers)
```

But I have not figured out how to change the value with a variable yet.
Thinking something like this might work.

```
    body = {'value': value}
    requests.put(host + 'registers/11', json=body, headers = headers)
```